# Analyzing differential equations system stability via phase diagram

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I´m having a hard time trying to understand how to analyze stability using the phase diagram method for systems, could you please guide me?
My result should be just knowing if we´re in front of a node, a saddle point, a focus, or a vortex and if they´re stable or not in the cases this applies.

I´d appreciate if you could use the example below as a case as it´s one of those I´m trying to solve.

\begin{cases}
x´=x^3+3x^2y+y \\
y´=y^2x+x
\end{cases}

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Amzoti, I know how to evaluate them but I´m trying to learn this method as I need to solve cases where I don´t have values but need a fast qualitative analysis.

Comment: No, I´m seeing some cases and the graphs but can´t understand well the procedure. The only book I found that explain the method was http://www.amazon.com/Fundamental-Methods-Mathematical-Economics-Wainwright/dp/0070109109, but I´m clearly not getting it.

Comment: Do you think you Could briefly explain me how to do the graph?